# Under linux / unix, how to discover if a directory is a link using c++?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

I'm trying to figure out how to find out if a directory is a symlink using c++

Figuring out if a file is a symlink is easy, using lstat and S_ISLNK(fs.st_mode) but this only seems to work on files. S_ISDIR always says that a directory is a directory, even if its actually a symlink pointing to a directory.

So, how do I do the same thing for a directory as a file?

Comment: What is the exact value (in octal) of the `st_mode` field for a sym link to a directory?  What does the `stat` command (at the command line) output for it?

Comment: real is a real directory, fake is a symlink to a the /tmp directory  st_mode in octal for real is 40755
st_mode in octal for fake is 40755

Answer (score 7):

The actual distinction is more subtle.  If you `lstat("/path/link/")` it will "look through" the symlink due to the trailing slash.  Your code should work if you do `lstat("/path/link")` (note no trailing slash).  You can see that in this python example (even without knowing what the numbers mean you can see the result change):

```
$ ln -s /etc /tmp/foo

>>> from posix import lstat
>>> lstat("/tmp/foo")
(41471, 24591, 64769L, 1, 1095, 501, 4, 1298667395, 1298667395, 1298667395)
>>> lstat("/tmp/foo/")
(16877, 131073, 64768L, 119, 0, 0, 12288, 1298663835, 1298667375, 1298667375)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to determine whether a given directory is a symlink is to read the link via `readlink`:

```
char buffer[255];
int size = readlink("/my/path", buffer);
if (errno == EINVAL) {
    /* here you know: "/my/path" isn't a symlink */
}
```

And of course: If you write `/my/path/` (with a trainling slash) then you actually mean: `/my/path/.` and this is never a symlink.